# Proving that the limit of an $L^p$ sequence is also $L^p$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I've been given this problem statement:

> Let $f_n$, $\phi \in L^p(\Omega)$, $p\in[1,\infty)$ s.t.:
>
> 1. $|f_n(x)|\leq\phi(x) $ a.e. in $\Omega$
> 2. $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ a.e. in $\Omega$
>
> Prove that $f\in L^p$

By the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, it can be seen that these conditions imply $\int_{\Omega} f_i \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} f \leq \int_{\Omega} \phi$. However, we need $||f||_p<+\infty $. Is this true because $|f|\leq\phi \implies |f|^p\leq|\phi|^p\implies \int_{\Omega}|f|^p\leq\int_{\Omega}|\phi|^p <+\infty$? Or do I need to show this last line somehow?

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: But how do we know $|f|\leq\phi$? Is that because the $f_n\leq\phi$? From $\int f\leq\int\phi$, do we know that $f\leq\phi$? Or should we use the absolute value to work with a nonnegative function?

Comment: For almost every $x$, $|f(x)|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)|\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}|\phi(x)|=\phi(x).$ So you you might change $|f|\leq\phi$ to $|f|\leq\phi$ a.e. in $\Omega$.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Sorry for grilling, my friend wants to show first that $|f_n|^p\rightarrow|f|^p$ before saying $|f|^p\leq|\phi|^p$. I'll discuss this with her. Thank you!

Comment: That follows from the continuity of the function $x\mapsto x^p$.